# c++ error: referenced in function _main when reading a file

Tags: c++

When I'm trying to read a file with a function

```
void readFile(string fileName, string* anArray) {
    unsigned int lineCounter = 0;
    ifstream inFile = ifstream(fileName);

    while (!inFile.eof()) {
        string fileLine;
        inFile >> fileLine;
        if (!fileLine.empty()) {
            anArray[lineCounter] = fileLine;
            ++lineCounter;
        }
    }
    inFile.close();
}
```

I get the error below, which I assume is because of the pointer on the string array ?

> 1>Main.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "void __cdecl
>   resource::readFile(class std::basic_string,class std::allocator >,class
>   std::basic_string,class
>   std::allocator > *)"
>   (?readFile@resource@@YAXV?$basic_string@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@V?$allocator@D@2@@std@@PAV23@@Z)
>   referenced in function _main

Comment: Pretty sure that's not the full error.

Comment: ups.. update incomming

Comment: It is complaining about not being able to find the definition of `resource::readFile`.  Which source file is it defined in, and are you linking to it?

Comment: Is `readFile` supposed to be a member function defined outside of the class `resource`? If so you likely meant `void resource::readFile(...) {`.

Comment: Yes yes, omg I left out the part...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
void readFile(string fileName, string* anArray) {
```

This is the definition of a member function, but you forgot to write the class name.

```
void resource::readFile(string fileName, string* anArray) {
```

As you have it now, you've defined a new function in the global namespace that has nothing to do with `resource`, so when `main` tries to use `resource::readFile`, the definition cannot be found.

Comment: @Xerath: Well, computers can't guess what you _meant_ to write but didn't!